# How to fetch opencv frames with ZeroMQ?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, networking, zeromq

I'm using the following code to fetch the frames from the client :

```
def fetch_frame(self):

    context = zmq.Context()
    footage_socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
    footage_socket.bind('tcp://*:5555')

    while True:
        frame = footage_socket.recv_string()

        frame = frame.encode()

        img = base64.b64decode(frame)

        npimg = np.fromstring(img, dtype=np.uint8)
        source = cv2.imdecode(npimg, 1)
```

Unfortunately, it is throwing the following error :

```
zmq.error.ZMQError: Operation cannot be accomplished in current state
```

What is the proper way to retrieve image using zmq?

***UPDATE:***

Following is the traceback :

```
 File "/home/receive/main.py", line 77, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/receive/main.py", line 73, in main
    ci.fetch_frame()
  File "/home/receive/main.py", line 59, in fetch_frame
    frame = footage_socket.recv_string()
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zmq/sugar/socket.py", line 608, in recv_string
    msg = self.recv(flags=flags)
  File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 791, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.recv
  File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 827, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.recv
  File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 191, in zmq.backend.cython.socket._recv_copy
  File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 186, in zmq.backend.cython.socket._recv_copy
  File "zmq/backend/cython/checkrc.pxd", line 26, in zmq.backend.cython.checkrc._check_rc
zmq.error.ZMQError: Operation cannot be accomplished in current state
```

Comment: **What** is throwing the error? Please edit your question and include the entire traceback (or at a minimum mention what line of your code is causing it).

Comment: @martineau please check the updated question. I have added the logs

Comment: _Yes_, that's the kind of information one should put into questions like this to help others figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Could the problem be at the other end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Q** : *"`ZMQError: Operation cannot be accomplished in current state`"*

The core reason is, that your code violated ZeroMQ `REQ/REP` documented properties.

Asking `REP`-instance to `.send()`-ed message before a **`REQ`**-instance has already "asked" its counterparty first, the API has to throw such error.

Similarly, if trying to `.recv()` a message on the `REQ`-side, before it has first "asked" by a `.send()` the `REP`-side ( to reply ), the API has to throw such error.

---

### SOLUTION ?

In a case no other interaction is needed, a `PUSH/PULL` Scalable Formal Communication Pattern Archetype, where `PUSH`-side will `.send()` & the `PULL`-side will `.recv()`, is IMHO the best way ahead.

---

You might like to read more tips and links about this in [*this*.](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/62236483/2)